# zend file transfer checking files

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-transfer

I want to check if a file has been uploaded or not. If not I don't want my form to update this field automatic. If it is uploaded I want this file to be uploaded in my db. Here is the code in my controller. In my form I've got an Zend_Form_Element_File('Document')

```
$upload = new Zend_File_Transfer();
$data['document'] = $upload->getFileInfo();
foreach ($data['document'] as $file => $info) {
  if ($upload->isUploaded($file)) {
  }
  if (!$upload->isUploaded($file)) {
  }
  // ...?
}
```

Thanks

Comment: you just want to know if file is uploaded or not right ?

Comment: no, my $data['document'] = blabla.txt, after uploading a file this blabla.txt will be replaced by the new file. But if not, i want to keep the blabla.txt. So I want to check if file is not uploaded how I need to keep my blabla.txt. You can see this as an editAction

Comment: if the file is not uploaded then the old file will be there, it won't be replaced right ??

Comment: the funny thing is that it will be replaced. :S

Comment: Got the answer myself:

    if ($data['document'] == null)
    {
        unset($data['document']);
    }

if nothing is added to the form. You only have to check if the array is null or not. If $data['document'] == null then you have to unset this $data['document'] so it will not be replaced with null and the old files will stay in this array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer myself:

```
if ($data['document'] == null)
{
    unset($data['document']);
}
```

if nothing is added to the form while editing it. You only have to check if the array is null or not. If $data['document'] == null then you have to unset this $data['document'] so it will not be replaced with null and the old files will still be

Answer (score 0):

From the [Zend documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.standardElements.html#zend.form.standardElements.file) for the Zend_Form_Element_File class, with comments added:

```
// check whether a file has been uploaded
if (!$form->foo->receive()) {
    print "Error receiving the file";
}

// get the file name
$location = $form->foo->getFileName();
```